# Search through podcast-episodes via API

Tags: json, api, itunes, podcast, itunes-search-api

I am looking for a service(API) to search through Podcasts and their episodes.

**Goal:** I would like to set a search term - football and the results are podcast episodes related to this term (Title, Description, Tag).

I looked into https://itunes.apple.com/search? from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/iTuneSearchAPI/Searching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017632-CH5-SW2  but unfortunately this just gives me the podcasts and not the episodes.

Do you have an idea how to reach my goal?

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

As of Jan 15, 2021, the iTunes API doesn't allow searching for episodes.

But you can try other 3rd party podcast APIs.

For example, Listen Notes API allows to search (almost) all publicly accessible RSS-based podcast episodes: https://www.listennotes.com/api/

[Screenshot of podcast search API docs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Vwc.png)

```
    import requests
    
    url = 'https://listen-api.listennotes.com/api/v2/search?q=star%20wars&sort_by_date=0&type=episode&offset=0&len_min=10&len_max=30&genre_ids=68%2C82&published_before=1580172454000&published_after=0&only_in=title%2Cdescription&language=English&safe_mode=0'
    headers = {
      'X-ListenAPI-Key': '',
    }
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
    print(response.json())
```

Disclaimer: I built Listen Notes API.